# Formulario guardar y rescatar datos de fichero txt

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un formulario que escriba los datos introducidos en un fichero .txt al pulsar "guardar datos" y luego los rescate y los muestre por pantalla al pulsar el botón "mostrar datos". No consigo que me aparezcan los datos. Dejo el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Formulario</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<FORM method="post" name="formulario">
Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

Apellido: <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
<input type="submit" value="Ver datos">

<?php
$archivo = "alumnos.txt";//
$gestor = @fopen("datos.txt", "w");

fclose($gestor);
?>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>



<?php
$nombre="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['nombre'])){
$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
}

$apellido="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['apellido'])){
$apellido=$_REQUEST['apellido'];

}

//Luego sobrescribo el txt

$archivo="datos.txt";

     $file=fopen($archivo,"w");
     fwrite($file,$nombre,$apellido);
  ?>
```

Comment: entre abrir y cerrar el archivo no hay código

Comment: Sí este.
<?php
$nombre="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['nombre'])){
$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
}
 
$apellido="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['apellido'])){
$apellido=$_REQUEST['apellido'];

}
 
//Luego sobrescribo el txt
 
$archivo="datos.txt";
 
     $file=fopen($archivo,"w");
     fwrite($file,$nombre,$apellido);
  ?>

Comment: agrega el código completo al cuerpo de la pregunta clickando en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205218/edit)

Comment: ya lo he puesto.

Comment: No, @Juan. Se refiere a que entre `fopen` y `fclose` no hay código. Esa parte que falta es la lectura de fichero. Si puedes ponlo en tu pregunta

Comment: En este caso es el php el que recoge los datos y los muestra

Comment: Pero antes y ciertas el archivo, pero no lees el contenido. No usas algo tipo `fread` en tu codigo

Comment: Es lo que pregunto, que no consigo hacerlo andar

Comment: Revisa que ya te puse una respuesta a ver si es lo que deseas realmente hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique un poco tu codigo para que funcionara mejor. Aunque todavia no se para que realmente necesitas guardarlo en un txt en tu servidor cuando con localStorage con javascript lo puedes hacer del lado del cliente. bueno nada aki va mi solución.

```
<?php 
//Declaro los textos que van a usar los botones de los submits
const GUARDAR = 'Guardar';
const VER_DATOS = 'Ver datos';
$datos = [];
//Inicializo las variables que contienen los valores de los inputs a null en caso de que no se haya enviado el formulario aún
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? null;
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'] ?? null;
//Si el metodo de la solicitud es un post es decir si se envio el formulario y la operacion tiene algun valor
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['operacion'])){
  //Si la operacion es la de guardar.....
  if($_POST['operacion'] === GUARDAR){
      //Abro el archivo para escribir
      $file = @fopen("archivo.txt", "a");        
      //Guardo el arreglo codificado a json
      fwrite($file, "$nombre,$apellido".PHP_EOL);
      //Cierro el archivo
      fclose($file);
      //Si quieres limpiar el formulario despues de guardar los datos descomentarea estas 2 lineas
      //$nombre = null;
      //$apellido = null;
  } else {
      //Si la operacion es la de Cargar o ver y el archivo existe
      if(file_exists('archivo.txt')){
          //Almaceno el contenido completo del archivo en esta variable
          $content = trim(file_get_contents('archivo.txt'), PHP_EOL);
          //Obtengo todas las entradas por lineas del archivo
          $lineas = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
          foreach($lineas as $linea){
              list($name, $last) = explode(',', $linea);
              $datos[] = ['nombre' => $name, 'apellido' => $last];
          }
      }
  }
}
//Cuerpo de la página
$body = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <FORM method="post" name="formulario" autocomplete="off">
    Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

    Apellido: <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="'.GUARDAR.'" name="operacion">
    <input type="submit" value="'.VER_DATOS.'" name="operacion">

    </FORM>';

if(!empty($datos)){
    $body .= '
        <br />
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
    ';
    foreach($datos as $elemento){
        $body .= '
            <tr><td>'.$elemento['nombre'].'</td><td>'.$elemento['apellido'].'</td></tr>
        ';
    }
    $body .= '</table>';
}
$body .= '
    </body>
    </html>';
//Renderizo el cuerpo de la página
echo $body;
```

Lo probe y funciona bien.

Comment: A mí no me funciona, además no quería utilizar json. Solo quiero que me guarde el nombre y los apellidos en un archivo .txt y que luego los muestre por pantalla.

Comment: El archivo txt sigue existiendo solo que tiene el formato json, es mucho mas facil de leer. Y no entiendo porque no te funciona sera tal vez por la version de php yo uso la 7.1 y solo era copiar y pegar

Comment: Pero solo me almacena un nombre y un apellidos, quiero que almacene varios nombres hasta que pulse el botón ver datos

Comment: A ver si entendi quieres ir guardandolos y cuando pulses ver datos verlos todos. Si es asi edita tu pregunta y pon mas información

Comment: Mira ver si asi es como lo quieres no obstante edita tu pregunta para que quede mas claro lo que estas buscando realizar. En la respuesta que te puse se guardan en un archivo de texto y cuando das en Ver traes del archivo el listado de los que has ido salvando y s emuestran en una tabla

Answer (score 0):

Una vez hice algo asi para un cliente que quiere guerdar sus notas en un .txt, algo muy simple, no solo agrega las notas, sino que también las muestra.

Funciona, espero te ayude. Saludos

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
 $nombre = "";
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['name'])){
   $nombre = $_REQUEST['name'];
}

$post = "";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['post'])){
 $post = $_REQUEST['post'];
}

$archivo = "notas.txt";
$file = fopen($archivo,"a");
fwrite($file,"[".$nombre."]"."\n".$post."\n".date('d/m/Y m:s')."\n"."\n");
fclose($file);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name" value="notas" placeholder="Notas"><br>
<textarea name="post" placeholder="Text"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
</form>

<?php
$ar = fopen("notas.txt","r") or die("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
while (!feof($ar)){
 $linea = fgets($ar);
 $lineasalto = nl2br($linea);
 echo $lineasalto;
}
fclose($ar);
?>
```